# How a set whose existence is guarantied by one formula can be substituted into another formula?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic

I try to combine the `Power Set Axiom` and the `Axiom Schema of Specification` to prove that for any given set there exist another set that contains the given one as its only element. Moreover, I would like to do it as formal / strict as possible.

So, I start from the following two statements:

$\forall X : \exists P : \forall p : [(p \in P) \Leftrightarrow (p \subseteq X)]$

$\forall X : \forall B : \exists Y : \forall y : [(y \in Y) \Leftrightarrow ((y \in B) \wedge (y = X))]$

One can think of these two statements as "functions". In the first case we take a set `X` and for this set we can "generate" set `P`. In the second case we take sets `X` and `B` and "generate" set `Y`. Now I want to combine these "functions". In more details, in the second formula for all `X` I would like to use its `P` (as defined by the first formula) instead of `B`. Or, in other words, in the second formula for any `X`, I can use any `B` and I decided to use `P` as `B`.

So, the first part of my question is: How can I substitute `B` by `P` formally? In other words, how can I write `P` instead of `B` in the second formula such that `P` comes in there together with its definition provided by the first formula?

The second part of my question (assuming that we can write a formula described by the first part of the question) is if we can make such step-by-step transformations of this formula to get the following formula:

$\forall X : \exists Y : \forall y : [(y \in Y) \Leftrightarrow (y = X)]$

Comment: With your recent questions there's an emerging trend which suggests that maybe it's a good idea to revise the basics of first-order logic before moving on further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is accomplished via [**existential instantiation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_instantiation), with [universal instantiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_instantiation) also playing a key role in the proof.

Specifically, we reason as follows:

- Introduce a symbol $u$ standing for an arbitrary set; we want to show, using the $\mathsf{ZFC}$ axioms, that $\exists Z\forall z(z\in Z\leftrightarrow z=u)$. If we can do this we'll apply universal generalization to conclude $\forall X\exists Z\forall z(z\in Z\leftrightarrow z=X)$ as desired.
- By powerset and universal instantiation, we get $\exists P\forall p(p\in P\leftrightarrow p\subseteq u)$.
- Now we apply existential instantiation: this lets us introduce a new symbol $v$ and the formula $\forall p(p\in v\leftrightarrow p\subseteq u)$.
- And **this** $v$ we can plug directly into an instance of the separation scheme as desired, via - again - universal instantiation.

Of course there are many different proof systems out there (e.g. compare [natural deduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_deduction#First_and_higher-order_extensions) and [Hilbert systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_system)), but the above sketch will go through with only minor elaboration in any of them that I'm aware of.